# Shell script that run ffmpeg with random url (newbie)

Tags: bash, ssh

I like to add the following to shell script: `encode.sh`

```
ffmpeg -i "URL" -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -acodec copy -vcodec copy "output.mp4"
```

and then i want somehow do like to do the following in SSH:

```
encode.sh "http://url"
```

this shall run `encode.sh` with the URL I specify.

Is this possible? If so please please help me write this!

Comment: yes, and it's probably on the first page of every bash scripting tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

In a bash script, $n refers to nth parameter/command line argument.

So if you want the first parameter to be put in the input file argument of ffmpeg, you will have to write it like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -i "$1" -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -acodec copy -vcodec copy "output.mp4"
```

http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Pass_arguments_into_a_function